# Whats the best way to store different prices for one entity in SQL?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

So I am building a webpage that shows a bunch of video games located in a SQL database and one suggestion I had was to have the different prices from each region display based on a drop down. My question is trying to figure out whats the best way to store int in the database. Would it be like:

- GAME

  - CountryID
  - price1
  - CountryID
  - price2
  - CountryID
  - price3 ...

Or is there a better way to do this?

Just a heads up I've only been developing web applications for a year or so and I'm still pretty new to SQL.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: It's not really clear what table structure you're implying from your example.  But if a Game can have multiple Prices then that at least implies a one-to-many relationship between two tables.  One table would store Games, and the other would store Prices with a foreign key to Games.  If you have a table of Countries then perhaps the GamePrices table would itself be a linking table in a many-to-many relationship between Games and Countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use multiple tables, one for games and one for region pricing.

Games

```
+--------+----------+
| GameID | GameName |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Game1    |
|      2 | Game2    |
|      3 | Game3    |
|      4 | Game4    |
+--------+----------+
```

RegionPricing

```
+----------+--------+-------+
| RegionID | GameID | Price |
+----------+--------+-------+
|        1 |      1 |    60 |
|        1 |      2 |    55 |
|        1 |      3 |    45 |
|        1 |      4 |    80 |
|        2 |      1 |    50 |
|        3 |      2 |    30 |
|        3 |      3 |    25 |
|        3 |      4 |    45 |
|        4 |      1 |    60 |
|        4 |      2 |    55 |
|        4 |      3 |    45 |
|        4 |      4 |    80 |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

By using separate tables you minimize duplicate data and allow for easy granular changes. You may also consider adding a column to RegionPricing for currency. This would also need a Region table, with RegionID and RegionName.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!